# How do you restrict specific content types per user role

Tags: users

I'm trying to restrict specific content types per user role so that some users can only edit certain content. I've tried configuring content access module but can't seem to restrict content types.

Comment: Check with the drupal default permissions /admin/people/permissions. For each content type and based on role, you can set permissions to create,edit or delete a content.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the permissions for each content type and role with Drupals default permissions.

Go to */admin/people/permissions* there is a section called *Node* where you can set the individual permissions for each content type:

- Create new content
- Edit own content
- Edit any content
- Delete own content
- Delete any content

Keep in mind that the permission *Bypass content access control* overrides the access restrictions of the individual content types. So if a role has this permission, the user can view, edit and delete all content.

Answer (score 0):

You do it by using Rules module:

1. Add a rule when user view nodes
2. Select content type where you want to view content for specific user role
3. In action add component or action to redirection i.e 301 user or show message Access denied